# Wordpress and DD's Ultimate Fade-in Slideshow: Code Doesn't Scroll Through Thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, wordpress

I am trying to use a Wordpress loop (of a certain category) to pull featured images, links, and excerpts and populate the Ultimate Fade in Slideshow JS. The code outputs the correct format, syntax, and shows the links to the two posts correctly. However, this code is not looping through the featured images. It seems to fade between the same image twice.

There are currently two posts in this specific category, both with images set as the featured. Each post also has an excerpt.

All documents (fadeslideshow.js and jQuery) are linked correctly in the header and upon watching the code using Safari's web inspector - the dynamic drive script shows the transparency changing - it is just switching between the same image so it appears that nothing is happening.

The code below is in a separate .php document that is called in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php query_posts('cat=7'); ?> //queries posts only from featured category
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({ 
wrapperid: "fadeshow", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
dimensions: [585, 350], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
imagearray: [

<?php   $thumbnails = get_posts('posts_per_page=5'); //adding category=7 here breaks code
        $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 
        $total = count($thumbnails); //this is to count the number of thumbnails in foreach loop to NOT add a comma to the last one
        $i=1;

        foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
        $i++;

         echo '["'.$url.'","'.get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ).'","","'.$my_excerpt.'"]'; //This spits out the exact correct code
         if ($i != $total) { echo', '; }//this is to count the number of thumbnails in foreach loop to NOT add a comma to the last one

 }} ?>
],

displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:3000, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
descreveal: "ondemand",
togglerid: ""
})

<?php endwhile; endif; ?> //This ends the wordpress loop
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</script>
```

Dynamic Drive's Ultimate Fade in Slide show information is here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

My code is on this website: http://johnharvey.hsjjr.net

I've also tried to use wp_get_attachment_image_src without success.

I have thoroughly searched on Google, the Dynamic Drive forums, and the Wordpress Codex without finding anything else to try. I believe perhaps I am not informed enough about what is going wrong to know what else to search for. I believe there is a reasonably simple solution to this, I simply do not have the experience to know what is going wrong.

Thank you all so much for you help and knowledge!

Comment: Additional notes - I noticed moving the script tag down (such as below the wordpress loop) or moving the wordpress loop down (just before defining the variables) breaks the entire code - no image displays.

Comment: It also appears to cycle between the links correctly. However, it does not cycle through the image (set as featured image in WP post) or WP excerpt...

Comment: Not entirely sure why this worked - but I solved the problem. Instead of defining the variables above the foreach loop, I moved it down into the loop:

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why this worked - but I solved the problem. Instead of defining the variables above the foreach loop, I moved it down into the loop:

```
<?php   $thumbnails = get_posts('posts_per_page=5'); //adding category=7 here breaks code

        $total = count($thumbnails); //this is to count the number of thumbnails in foreach loop to NOT add a comma to the last one
        $i=1;

        foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
        $i++;



         echo '["'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($thumbnail->ID) ).'","'.get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ).'","","'.get_the_excerpt($thumbnail->ID).'"]'; //This spits out the exact correct code
         if ($i != $total) { echo', '; }//this is to count the number of thumbnails in foreach loop to NOT add a comma to the last one


 }

}
?>
```

The except still does not cycle through, but at least the thumbnails do.